# this keyword as a reference variable

Tags: java, this

**this** is a variable which holds the reference ID of the current object.
So why it cannot be used as a reference variable ?

```
Temp t = new Temp();  //Temp be any class
t.show();            //show() be any method in Temp
this.show();        // error
```

Comment: That **wont** thrown an error **unless** you are not in `Temp` class or you are in `Temp` class but in a static context.

Answer (score 3):

That will only throw an error if the class you're in does not have a `show()` method *or* if you are trying to do that from a static context.

`this` hold the reference ID of the current object so it depends where you are and *not* what objects you've just created.

Comment: what does then "current object" means?

Comment: @anmolsharma Think of it as the class you are in.

Answer (score 0):

Current object is not an object you referred last. Here is example of `this` usage:

```
public class Temp {
    private int x = 3;

    public void show() {
        this.x = 4;
        this.show(); // same as show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "this" keyword in java is to reference the object the code is running in. 
It is mostly useful you are comparing the object within itself. Example:

```
 public boolean equals(Object object) {
      return object == this;
 }
```

Here is another snippet of code to help you understand:

```
 public class Test {

      public Test() {
      }

      public static void main(String... args) {
           Test test = new Test();//original test object
           Test test2 = new Test();
           test.equals(test);//returns true
           test.equals(test2);//returns false
      }

      public void equals(Test testParameter) {

           // in this particular case "this" refers to the 
           // original test object (defined in the main method)
           // as it is the only object calling this method.
           return testParameter == this; // "this" is the object that is calling the method
      }

 }
```